# Switch between Views according to TreeView SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, prism

i can't find a solution to this problem.
i have a treeview, and i'm trying to get to the point where i'm clicking/double clicking and it opens a view on a different part of the window(lets say using a gridsplitter and the tree is on the right and the relevant view will open on the left by setting the contentcontrol content DP).

thanks

Comment: Can you post your xaml code for the tree view please ?

Comment: really doesn't matter... it can be a treeview with a single treeviewitem

Comment: You can use tree view.selectedItem, cast it to your binded object and use it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I used 
[Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) 
to build my Treeview.

my xaml looks like :

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents,IsAsync=True}" Name="tree" SelectedItemChanged="tree_SelectedItemChanged"  Background="Transparent" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:XMLParentViewModel}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition MinHeight="20" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentDisplayText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:XMLChildViewModel}">
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="20" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildDisplayText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown" />
                </Grid >
            </DataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

and the to know what kind of element is selected :

```
private void tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if( tree.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(XMLChildViewModel))
            //Do what you need
    }
```

I can adapt this code for you but if you have more questions

Comment: i need that on the right side of the window (second column for example) there will be a contentcontrol and i'll set its content to a different usercontrol according to the selected TreeViewItem

Comment: use tree.SelectedItem to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What clemens said, but also I have a hard time understanding what the problem/issue is? All the help we can get understanding your question, will make all the help you get even better :)

Comment: I think he wants to show a different content according to the type of selected item. Simple example with car brand and models, if you select a brand, you display information on the brand, if you select a model, display the model. the information about brand and model can be 2 difference controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think This will help. Here the XAML Code...

```
<TreeView Name="treenavigator" Grid.Row="1">
          <TreeViewItem DisplayMemberPath="Item" Header="Item" Name="navitem">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Add Item" Name="additem" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Update Item Details" Name="updateitem" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="View Item Details" Name="viewitemdetails" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Delete Items" Name="deleteitem" />
          </TreeViewItem> 
</TreeView>
```

Here the Sample C# Code. `grdForm` is the grid in main window that I load the User Controller, and `AddItem` is the User Controller That I load into `grdForm`.

```
private void navitem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      if (treenavigator.SelectedValue.ToString() == additem.ToString())
      {
            AddItem ItemView = new AddItem();
            grdform.Children.Add(ItemView);
       }
}
```